# Finding valuations/uniformizers for the branches of the blow up of a singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I understand that for a nonsingular curve $C(x,y)$, the uniformizer at a point $(a,b)$ is either $x-a$ or $y-b$, since the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are not both 0.

However, if we have the singular curve $y^2=x^7+xy$, is there some way to find the uniformizer at the singular point $(0,0)$ by blowing up the curve?

What I've tried so far:

Following the method in https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~jcouveig/cours/course7.pdf, we can desingularize the curve by setting $y=tx$ and we get $x^5=t^2-t$.

I believe the paper says that $t$ and $t-1$ are the two uniformizing parameters (for the two branches), but it doesn't seem like I can write $x=t^a\cdot u$, where $a$ is a some positive integer.

I'm not very familiar with algebraic geometry, so my understanding of what's going on might be completely off. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why should there be a uniformizer at a singular point?

Comment: I meant to say the uniformizers at the two branches in the blow up (as explained in the first example of https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~jcouveig/cours/course7.pdf)